# Problema con GEO activada y sin Lat ni Long en Tweet's con Tweepy y Python

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-api

Creo que en la pregunta he dicho todo.

Uso Python 3.5, Tweepy y después de una búsqueda (search) de tweets a través de una palabra clave, veo que muchos tienen la `GEO` activa pero no puedo acceder a `Lat` y `Lng` usando Tweepy.

¿Alguien sabe dónde están esos campos y cuál sería la sintaxis exacta para acceder en el caso que existiesen?

[image: Porque esta porcion de codigo no trae ningun dato ?]

Comment: Dale una mirada a esto a ver si te sirve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889122/how-to-add-a-location-filter-to-tweepy-module

Comment: Quizas este mal formulada la pregunta, no busco por ubicacion, es una busquedad generica, al hacer el analisis del json veo que hay muchas cuentas que tienen el GEO activado, pero no encuentro la LAT y LONG de los mismos. He leido que no es obligatorio que los traiga, pero en el caso que trajera el json la Lat y Long, donde se encuentran y cual seria la sintaxis correcta para acceder a esos datos ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, cabe resaltar que el campo `geo` del [API de Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) ha sido deprecado:

> Deprecated. Nullable. Use the “coordinates” field instead. [Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/nk6nUXgXSQg)

Lo correcto es usar el campo [`coordinates`](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets#obj-coordinates):

> The longitude and latitude of the Tweet’s location, as an collection in the form of [longitude, latitude].

Ejemplo:

```
"coordinates":[-97.51087576,35.46500176]
```

Ten en cuenta que no todos los tweets tienen geolocalización por lo que tendrías que validar antes el campo. Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo que acabo de hacer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tweepy


# Tus credenciales
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
public_tweets = api.search('#python')
for tweet in public_tweets:
    if tweet.coordinates:
        print tweet.coordinates
        print tweet.coordinates['coordinates']
```

Una salida de ejemplo sería:

```
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [106.86663792, -6.16509361]}
[106.86663792, -6.16509361]
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente !
Numero de seguidores de este usuario: 485 
GEO activa: True 
Coordenadas: [106.86663792, -6.16509361] 
Cuenta creada el: 2012-06-27 09:18:29 
Este tweet fue enviado el: 2016-02-21 17:26:43 
Desde que dispositivo envio el Tweet: Instagram
Excelente !

Comment: @papabomay perfecto!